# Audio Player - How to play next and prev songs using ListView

Tags: android, listview, audio

Writing a small Audio player in which i want to allow user to play prev and next songs whenever user do tap on respective button, i am using listview for listing all the songs

```
private int currentSongIndex = 0;

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
    long id) {                  

     strNURL = videoMovieArrayList.get(position).getUrl().toString();
     strNTITLE = videoMovieArrayList.get(position).getTitle().toString();

             if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                   try {
                           mediaPlayer.stop();
                        } catch (Exception e) {     
                    }
                          play(arg1);
                          textTrack.setText(strNTITLE);
                        }
                 });        
            }

    public void play(View view){    
       mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
       mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strNURL);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        .......................

      mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
            playButton.setEnabled(true);                
           }
       });
   }

   public void prev(View view){ 
        Toast.makeText(MusicTrackActivity.this, "Previous song !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       if(currentSongIndex > 0){
          // play(currentSongIndex - 1);
           currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
       }else{
           // play last song
           // playSong(videoMovieArrayList.size() - 1);
           currentSongIndex = videoMovieArrayList.size() - 1;
       }
   }

   public void next(View view){ 
        Toast.makeText(MusicTrackActivity.this, "Next song !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(currentSongIndex < (videoMovieArrayList.size() - 1)){        
             // play(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{          
            // play(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
   }
```

So now my query is How can i switch to Next song, whenever user do tap on next button, as you can see in above code, i am simply showing Toast message

Answer (score 1):

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


             int  currentSongIndex= 0; 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                    playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                    currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                }else{
                    // play first song
                    plysong(songindex);
                }







            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep track of the index of the song that is playing in a variable, say `current`.

Assuming your underlying data for the adapter stores URI of the songs in an `ArrayList` and the user presses 'next', check if `current + 1` falls out of the `ArrayList`. If it does, don't play the song. However, if it doesn't, get the data from the `ArrayList`, reset your `MediaPlayer` and  `setDataSource()` for your `MediaPlayer`.